# Padding outside flex

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

How can I set padding on flex outside columns - left and right, if I want columns to be more to inside? I am using Bootstrap, but I wouldn't like to set col-md-offset-1 or similar.

Currently if I set `padding: 0 50px;` on `.row` or on `.flex`, columns won't have the same height.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWPzOp

```css
.row {
  padding: 0 50px;
  background-color: #333;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  /* Safari */
  justify-content: space-around;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-around;
  /* Safari 6.1+ */
}
.col-md-4 {} 

.col-inside {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="flex">

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-inside">
          <p>lorem asdf pdsfpds asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fda f asdf pdsfp asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fddsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fdds</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-inside">
          <p>lorem a asdf pdsfpdsa asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fdasdf pdsfpdsa fd fdsdf asdf pdsfpdsa fdpdsfp asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsf asdf pdsfpdsa fd as asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fddf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fdpdsa fd asdf
            pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fddsa fds</p>
        </div>
      </div>


      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="col-inside">
          <p>lorem asd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pds asdf pdsfpdsa fdfpdsa asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf p asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fddsfpdsa fd asdf pdsfpdsa fdfdf pdsfpdsa fds</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `margin` instead of `padding` and to get columns same height you can use `display: flex` on `.col-md-4` [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/787/) also maybe you want to put that in media query [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/788/)

```css
.col-md-4 {
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: flex;
}
.col-inside {
  background-color: #aaa;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Hm I thought of that, but I wouldn't like to set margin on columns because I would like to keep default small padding between them (also just setting margin-left on first column and margin-right on third column). Surely flex must have its easier ways of just setting space around...

Comment: Hm but it works if I set display: flex on col-md-4 and outside wrapper, and padding on outside row without setting margin on col-md-4 :)